# Need help choosing database server

Tags: c#, .net, c++, database, database-design

Good day everyone.

Recently I was given a task to develop an application to automate some aspects of stocks trading. While working on initial architecture, the database dilemma emerged. What I need is a fast database engine which can process huge amounts of data coming in very fast. I'm fairly experienced in general programming, but I never faced a task of developing a high-load database architecture. I developed a simple MSSQL database schema with several many-to-many relationships during one of my projects, but that's it.

What I'm looking for is some advice on choosing the most suitable database engine and some pointers to various manuals or books which describe high-load database development.

Specifics of the project are as follows:

- OS: Windows NT family (Server 2008 / 7)
- Primary platform: .NET with C#
- Database structure: one table to hold primary items and two or three tables with foreign keys to the first table to hold additional information.
- Database SELECT requirements: Need super-fast selection by foreign keys and by combination of foreign key and one of the columns (presumably DATETIME)
- Database INSERT requirements: The faster the better :)

If there'll be significant performance gain, some parts can be written in C++ with managed interfaces to the rest of the system.

So once again: given all that stuff I just typed, please give me some advice on what the best database for my project is. Links or references to some manuals and books on the subject are also greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'll need to insert 3-5 rows in 2 tables approximately once in 30-50 milliseconds and I'll need to do SELECTs with 0-2 WHERE clauses with similar rate.

Comment: Does it have to be a SQL-based database? There are specialized databases for high-frequency trading. One expensive database that is used a lot is Kdb+, see http://kx.com/.

Comment: @stephan No, it doesn't have to be a SQL-based database. Thanks for the link, we'll consider Kdb+ as one of the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technology is irrelevant. This is about hardware.

> Need super-fast selection by foreign
>   keys and by combination of foreign key
>   and one of the columns (presumably
>   DATETIME)

So you need something like a supermicro 72 disc computer system filled with SSD's and 256gb memory as cache. Simple as that. Addd processors as needed.

Problem is that it is EXPENSIVE, but at the end databases are about IO. Point.

Alternatively go with a click stream database (KD+) and intead of paying 30.000 USD for hardware they ask for 20.000 USD For the smallest software license to start.

I know this sounds hard, but adatabase speed - unless you do stupid things that kill performance - IS about hardware. PRettym uch the IOPS budget (independent IOPS per second). And not about software.

Comment: Yes, you are obviously right to say that the main bottleneck to database performance is IO. I just thought that maybe some database will perform slightly better in the the specified environment than the others.

Comment: Yes, but that will not be relevant compard to the IO impact from the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

That list of yours are just basic requirements. You can use almost any database for that, although I wouldn't recommend MySQL. It can slow down a little when you do many inserts, because this clears you query cache. Other DBMSs handle this better.

But then again. Three tables... you could almost do it in Access.

What you *didn't* specify is the amount of reads and inserts you expect. Our poor little MySQL database runs millions of queries a day for our website. Only a small part of this are inserts and updates (DML statements), so MySQL handles this very well, but the amount of queries, their complexity and the amount of data involved are more important data than the number of tables.

Comment: Yes, I most definitely can do it in Access, but will it be fast? :)  I can provide more details about the project if that helps.

Comment: Access will not be fast. If you are considering something file based, use Sql Server Compact Edition.

Comment: Edited my post to include information on INSERTs and SELECTs. I'm considering every option, but taking into account huge amounts of data, I really doubt that all that stuff will fit into RAM. What I need ideally is something that holds the most recent records in memory and dumps the old stuff to disk.

Comment: @The Pretender Have you considered using a cache layer like memcache or Microsoft's Velocity?

Comment: @tdaines Thanks, we weren't aware of that library. Actually we were thinking about writing something like Velocity ourselves, but since there's an existing solution, we'll surely give it a shot.

Comment: Access can be pretty fast, but I don't really wanted to suggest access. Just trying to make a point about small specs. :) Thanks for adding the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Where you already have experience with Sql Server, I would suggest sticking with it in some form. Also, Sql Server and .NET have a nice synergy going (obviously) because they are both Microsoft products.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be SQL, maybe a system like [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) is a good option. These kind of databases are used by high frequency websites like social media. Don't know how it installs under Windows server, though.